# Open Media Framework library for Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, audio, video, multimedia

Does anybody know of any library to process `omf` files in Java or Scala?

This format correspond to [Open Media Framework Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Media_Framework_Interchange) files.

Comment: I am not saying it doesn't exist, but if it did, I would probably know about it, and I don't.